# Explanation for weird behavious when ios::sync_with_stdio(0) and cin.tie(0) are written inside loop

Tags: c++

The input I am giving is

```
5
1 1 1 1 1
```

Can someone explain me this behaviour?

I actually found this during a online competitive programming contest. I was getting wrong answer verdict. While on my computer it worked fine, online IDEs gave a runtime error (Bus error). So I tried the below code (which is actually different than the original problem solution) but the principle I guess remains the same. If I get enough insight from this explanation, I might also understand the original solution errors. If not I will put additional queries.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t, a = 9;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
        cin.tie(0);
        cin >> a;
        cout << a;
    }
}
```

The below code when run on online ide gives output as:
99999
(I tested on codechef.com/ide and ide.geeksforgeeks.org)

While on my computer terminal (Ubuntu, g++) it gives output as:
11111
(This is true when I pass a input file to it or manually enter data in terminal)

This weird behavior is only when the two statements are inside the while loop. When written above the while loop, the output is as expected.

Comment: Apart from that, why would you put `ios::sync_with_stdio(0);` and `cin.tie(0);` inside a loop body?

Comment: I won't do it on purpose, I just added that by mistake and got a wrong answer verdict. I couldn't figure it out until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio):

> If [ios::sync_with_stdio] is called after I/O has occurred on the standard stream, the behavior is implementation-defined: implementations range from no effect to destroying the read buffer.

So you should not be calling this function inside your loop.  Instead, just call it once at the start of `main`:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/fhpRNUGCXDef1bw4

Comment: Oh! I understand. So on my computer the buffer is unchanged but on the online IDE it is destroyed.

Comment: Seems reasonable, yes.  Feel free to accept my answer :)